# i have questions about docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, postgresql

postgres:

```
image: healthcheck/postgres:alpine
environment:
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
```

- What is the default user of postgresql?
- How does hardcoding the postgres user improve security?
- What special rights does the postgres user have?
- What is the upside and downside of using an unprivileged user in this scenario?
- Is it necessary in our scenario to have an unprivileged user?

Answer (score 1):

I searched for the **healthcheck/postgres:alpine** and I found the following repository with the **Dockerfile**:

https://github.com/docker-library/healthcheck/blob/master/postgres/Dockerfile.alpine

Assuming this is the correct repo for your docker image, the dockerfile specifies:

```
FROM postgres

COPY docker-healthcheck /usr/local/bin/

HEALTHCHECK CMD ["docker-healthcheck"]
```

So it extends the postgres docker image which is documented here:

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Specifically for the password they mention the following:

> POSTGRES_PASSWORD This environment variable is recommended for you to
>   use the PostgreSQL image. This environment variable sets the superuser
>   password for PostgreSQL. The default superuser is defined by the
>   POSTGRES_USER environment variable.
>
> Note 1: The PostgreSQL image sets up trust authentication locally so
>   you may notice a password is not required when connecting from
>   localhost (inside the same container). However, a password will be
>   required if connecting from a different host/container...

Read the whole documentation at the image homepage.